# Problemas com acentuação ao ler dados de arquivo JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, codificação-de-caracteres

O método abaixo esta extraindo dados de um arquivo JSON, para preencher um DropDownList.

```
public static List<Uf> GetAll()
{
  var client = new WebClient();
  JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
  settings.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
  var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/uf.json")));
  var lista = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Uf>>(response, settings);
  return lista;
}
```

Mas quando retorna isso para o Browser, exibe os caracteres com acentuação com códigos extranhos.

[image: Texto com caracteres extranhos]

Como posso exibir os caracteres com acentuação correta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possivelmente o problema não tem a ver com a deserialização e sim com o *download* em si.

Definir o *encoding* na requisição deve resolver seu problema

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/uf.json")));
```

Comment: Eu estava tentando mudar o encoding na hora de apresentar os dados, mas não na hora de fazer o download. Funcionou. Obrigado.