# Remoção de caracter especial da string não funciona. c#

Tags: c#

Tenho esta `string`:

```
EM RECUPERA�?�?O
```

Essa string me vem em um `XML` e utilizo o seguinte código para tratar isso:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlRetorno);
xmlRetorno = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Mas não está funcionando. Continua do mesmo jeito.

Assim eu retorno o XML:

```
public string EnviarXmlSoap(string methodName, string body, string url)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/" + methodName);
        httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        //Create Stream and Complete Request             
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        StringBuilder soapRequest = new StringBuilder("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"");
        soapRequest.Append(" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ");
        soapRequest.Append("xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:"+methodName+"\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"> <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body>");
        soapRequest.Append(body);
        soapRequest.Append("</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>");

        streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString());
        streamWriter.Close();

        string xml = soapRequest.ToString();

        //Get the Response    
        HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
        string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
        return resulXmlFromWebService;
    }
```

Comment: qual é o código que recupera esse `XML`? me parece que o erro está antes e não nesse momento. Se puder colocar o código na pergunta !

Comment: Dentro do XML está com os carácteres normais ou com este `�?`? É melhor você adicionar na pergunta a forma como faz o download deste arquivo, possivelmente o problema está no download e não na forma de abrir, igual acontece [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157849/18246)

Comment: eu testei no Soap UI e o xml já vem assim...

Comment: @novato como você faz o código de resgate do `xml`?

Comment: @novato acredito que o `.ToString` esteja ocorrendo isto. pegue o retorno do `XML` em uma `var` e utilize um método que resgate o `XML`, no meu caso em envio e retorno de `XML` eu utilizo schemas para serializar e disserializar o mesmo com padrões `unicode` e `encoding`. Faça apenas para teste.

Comment: @novato é acho que é codificação WebService, talvez seja outra codificação tem que pesquisar isso.